# Return all rows that have the same id based on a value on one of the rows of a different column

Tags: mysql

I would like to return all rows that have the same id on columnA based on a value on one of the rows of a different column say ColumnB. The joined table results look like the below, I would like to return all results that do not have at least one instance of the value I am looking for.

In the example below, I would like to list all organizations that have not been contacted at all which means the organizationname or id which does not have the value 'Contacted' in the ConStatus column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWyO5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `Subquery`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE OrgId NOT IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT OrgId
     FROM table
     WHERE ConStatus = 'Contacted'
)
```

The subquery will get all organization IDs which are contacted. These IDs will then be excluded using `NOT IN` to get the ones which are never contacted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery with `not exists`

```
select * from tablename a
 where not exists 
     (select 1 from tablename b where a.orgid=b.orgid and ConStatus = 'Contacted')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table
    WHERE OrgId NOT IN (
         SELECT  OrgId
         FROM table
         WHERE ConStatus = 'Contacted'
    )
```